# Tensorflow: How to restore trained variables, but not the full model?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

In Tensorflow, how do I restore variables from a .index or .data file? 
I don't want the entire model, I just want four variables.

Here is what I have been trying:

```
save_dest = "my_path\\model_name" ## name of saved session

## Set 1:
w1 = tf.Variable([11,11,1,12])
w1_bias = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(12))  
w2 = tf.Variable([7, 7, 12, 32])
w2_bias = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(32))

## Set 2:
#   w1 = [v for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES) if 
v.name=="w1"][0] 
#w1_bias = [v for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES) if 
v.name=="w1_bias"][0] 
#w2 = [v for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES) if 
v.name=="w2"][0] 
#w1_bias = [v for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES) if 
v.name=="w2_bias"][0] 

## Set 3:
#w1 = tf.get_variable("w1",shape=[4])
#w1_bias = tf.get_variable("w1_bias",shape=[1])  
#w2 = tf.get_variable("w2",shape=[4])
#w2_bias = tf.get_variable("w2_bias",shape=[1])
print("________________")
print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(save_dest,tensor_name='',all_tensors=False)
print("________________")

# saver1 = tf.train.import_meta_graph(save_dest+".meta")   
#saver1 = tf.train.Saver(["w1:0","w1_bias:0","w2:0","w2_bias:0"])
#tf.reset_default_graph()
#saver1 = 
tf.train.Saver({"w1":w1,"w1_bias":w1_bias,"w2":w2,"w2_bias":w2_bias})
#saver1 = tf.train.Saver(var_list=["w1","w1_bias","w2","w2_bias"])
#saver1 = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as session:
    saver1 = tf.train.Saver()    
    tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    #saver1 = tf.train.import_meta_graph(save_dest)
    #saver1 = 
tf.train.Saver({"w1":w1,"w1_bias":w1_bias,"w2":w2,"w2_bias":w2_bias})

    #saver1.restore(session,save_dest)
    saver1.restore(session, save_dest)
    #w1 = [v for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES) if 
                 v.name=="w1:0"][0] 
    #w1_bias = [v for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES) 
                 if v.name=="w1_bias:0"][0] 
    #w2 = [v for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES) if 
                v.name=="w2:0"][0] 
    #w1_bias = [v for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES) 
                if v.name=="w2_bias:0"][0] 

    g = tf.get_default_graph()

    w1 = g.get_tensor_by_name("w1:0")
    w1_bias = g.get_tensor_by_name("w1_bias:0")
    w2 = g.get_tensor_by_name("w2:0")
    w2_bias = g.get_tensor_by_name("w2_bias:0")


    #preds = session.run(model(tf_valid_dataset))
    #test_prediction = session.run(model(valid_dataset),
    #                        feed_dict={keep_prob:1.0})

    print(np.shape(preds), type(preds))
```

Essentially I have been reading the answers from related questions (mostly how to restore a model) and trying to implement it. But, it always raises some sort of error. The only items in the current save_dest are trained parameter matrices named "w1", "w1_bias", "w2", "w2_bias". I.e.

```
 w1 (DT_FLOAT) [11,11,1,12]  
 w1_bias (DT_FLOAT) [12]  
 w2 (DT_FLOAT) [7,7,12,32]  
 w2_bias (DT_FLOAT) [32]
```

Errors that are raised included variable_01 does not exist, or dimension 4 object cannot fit into shape [11,11,1,12], among others. I am at a loss for how to fix this problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: passing a list of variables or a map from variable name to variables to the saver should work. Can you show the stack trace for one failing version?